# Does Elemental Affinity apply to spells cast from Magic Items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, sorcerer

Well, the title question is straight-forward. Elemental Affinity states

> Starting at 6th level, when *you cast* a spell that deals damage of the type associated with your draconic ancestry, add your Charisma modifier to that damage.

For example, Wand of Fireballs states

> While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 or more of its charges *to cast the Fireball spell (save DC 15) from it*.

Note that Elemental Affinity does not require the Cast a Spell action, however, it requires that *you* are the one casting the spell. Does it count if it comes *from the magic item*? I feel that this should be an easy answer but I'm a little confused here.